# How to check if X is child of Y or vice versa in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the structure below (around 1 million rows).
Let's say I have two id's (`X` and `Y`), how could I check efficiently if `X` is a child (any level) of `Y`, or vice versa? My MySQL server version is 5.7.

**Pseudo-code**

```
IF X is child of Y:
    SELECT hierarchy from Y to X
ELSE IF Y is child of X:
    SELECT hierarchy from X to Y
ELSE:
    SELECT nothing
```

**Database structure**

```
parent_id | child_id | child_level
----------------------------------
1         | 5        | 1
1         | 6        | 1
1         | 2        | 1
2         | 7        | 2
2         | 8        | 2
2         | 9        | 2
2         | 4        | 2
2         | 3        | 2
3         | 10       | 3
3         | 11       | 3
4         | 12       | 3
4         | 13       | 3
4         | 14       | 3
```

Comment: Does the answer here answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use that answer with two inputs. That example uses a single input and takes all child. Is there no way to do this with two inputs? I think that would lead to two queries with their approach: X and Y. Not?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recusive query - available in MySQL 8.0 only:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select root_id parent_id, child_id from mytablbe where parent_id = :X
    union all
    select c.root_id, t.child_id 
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parent_id = c.child_id
)
select * from cte where child_id = :Y
```

This query checks if `:X` is a parent of `:Y`: if yes, then one row is returned, else no row is returned.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention my MySQL server is v5.7